# Android camera preview is not resumed after Pause

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I successfully created a camera surface view, and it works when the app is started/restarted. But it just shows a black screen, after I pause the game and resume it (pressing home screen). Am I missing something here?

Here's the code for the surface (which is created from a Main Activity:

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

static Camera camera = null;
Surface camSurface;
String TAG = "CameraView";
static SurfaceHolder mHolder;

public CameraView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.e(TAG, "Camera view created");

    mHolder = getHolder();

    if(camera == null){
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    if(camera == null){
        Log.e(TAG, "Null camera");
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized(mHolder){
        if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you leave and return to your app, you still need to call  camera.startPreview() at some point. I would have this in my surfaceChanged() method.

Make sure you have a valid instance of your camera as when you first start it up.